# Temporal Table : specific column changed version details only

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

Need help/ideas on querying temporal table. I have SQL versioning enabled on table. This table have currently 15 columns.

The exact requirement is to identify how many times a "OrderStatus" column gets updated and who updated it at what time? We are only looking to see how many times "OrderStatus" column get updated between a specific date with all the other columns selected by default.

Comment: Be clearer on this: you only want to get the rows (with all columns) that changed if that column has also changed? Or you only want changed values in that column? If the latter, do you ever need the changed values in the other columns?

Comment: @Charlieface I want all rows from temporal table when 1 specific column get updated only. Suppose "Orderstatus" is the column name we are looking for and whenever their is an update happen on "Orderstatus" then query will return version details (all rows) from temporal table where only "Orderstatus" column get updated only. We want to exclude those rows when the "orderstatus" is not updated and other columns get revised.

Comment: And you want all the columns also, or just that column? Do you need the new value or also the old value?

Comment: Yes need all column also. Requirement is to track who updated this column and when and what other changes got updated when this column get revised.

Comment: You'd need a query that gets all row versions, then you can use LAG to see what the previous value was, and hence versions where the value changed

Comment: You have both `mysql` and `sql-server` tagged. Which is it?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is lacking in some details, so I've made *an attempt* based on a number of assumptions.

### [re-]Create Representative Table

```sql
IF Object_ID('dbo.orders', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.orders SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
  END
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.orders_history;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.orders;

CREATE TABLE dbo.orders (
   OrderId     int         NOT NULL IDENTITY(9,37)
 , OrderStatus varchar(20) NOT NULL
 , UpdatedBy   varchar(20) NOT NULL
 , ValidFrom   datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
 , ValidTo     datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
 , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
 , CONSTRAINT pk_dbo_orders PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)
WITH (
  SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
    HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.orders_history
  )
);
```

### Create Sample Data

Note the use of `WAITFOR` is to provide some more illustrative gaps between events.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.orders (OrderStatus, UpdatedBy)
  VALUES ('NEW', 'George')
       , ('NEW', 'George')
;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

UPDATE dbo.orders
SET    OrderStatus = 'IN PROGRESS'
WHERE  OrderId = 9
;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

-- Mark both orders as despatched
UPDATE dbo.orders
SET    OrderStatus = 'DESPATCHED'
;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

-- Whoops, order #46 wasn't supposed to be marked as dispatched
UPDATE dbo.orders
SET    OrderStatus = 'IN PROGRESS'
WHERE  OrderId = 46
;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

-- Mark it as in progress again, but changing the person who did the operation
UPDATE dbo.orders
SET    OrderStatus = 'IN PROGRESS'
     , UpdatedBy   = 'Not George'
WHERE  OrderId = 46
;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

-- _Now_ it is despatched
UPDATE dbo.orders
SET    OrderStatus = 'DESPATCHED'
     , UpdatedBy   = 'George'
WHERE  OrderId = 46
;
```

#### Raw Data

Let's take a peek at the raw data

```sql
SELECT OrderId
     , OrderStatus
     , UpdatedBy
     , ValidFrom
     , ValidTo
FROM   dbo.orders FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
ORDER
    BY OrderId
     , ValidFrom
;
```

| OrderId | OrderStatus | UpdatedBy | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | NEW | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:35.1632525 | 2021-02-17 10:27:37.1719903 |
| 9 | IN PROGRESS | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:37.1719903 | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 |
| 9 | DESPATCHED | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| 46 | NEW | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:35.1632525 | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 |
| 46 | DESPATCHED | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 | 2021-02-17 10:27:41.1995704 |
| 46 | IN PROGRESS | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:41.1995704 | 2021-02-17 10:27:43.2171042 |
| 46 | IN PROGRESS | Not George | 2021-02-17 10:27:43.2171042 | 2021-02-17 10:27:45.2328908 |
| 46 | DESPATCHED | Still Not George | 2021-02-17 10:27:45.2328908 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |

### Query Time

```sql
; WITH _orders AS (
  SELECT OrderId
       , OrderStatus
       , UpdatedBy
       , ValidFrom
       , ValidTo
       , Lead(OrderStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY ValidFrom) AS NextOrderStatus
  FROM   dbo.orders FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL
)
SELECT OrderId
     , OrderStatus
     , UpdatedBy
     , ValidFrom
FROM   _orders
WHERE  OrderStatus <> NextOrderStatus -- Only return records where the order status has changed
OR     NextOrderStatus IS NULL -- Include the "most recent" record in the results, always.
ORDER
    BY OrderId
     , ValidFrom
;
```

#### Results

| OrderId | OrderStatus | UpdatedBy | ValidFrom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | NEW | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:35.1632525 |
| 9 | IN PROGRESS | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:37.1719903 |
| 9 | DESPATCHED | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 |
| 46 | NEW | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:35.1632525 |
| 46 | DESPATCHED | George | 2021-02-17 10:27:39.1852032 |
| 46 | IN PROGRESS | Not George | 2021-02-17 10:27:43.2171042 |
| 46 | DESPATCHED | Still Not George | 2021-02-17 10:27:45.2328908 |

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with what you are trying to do is that the history table does not say which columns have been updated.**

What we need to do then, is first query all rowversions between those dates, and then use `LAG/LEAD` to check if the row has changed.

**Problem:** if we ask for the given dates, we do not get the version before that. We need to query the table again for that. Using `BETWEEN` (inclusive) instead of `FROM` (exclusive) on the main query makes this more difficult, as we then have to find a way to get the row `< @start`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pkID ORDER BY SysStartTime) rn,   -- or whatever your startTime column is called
        LAG(OrderStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY pkID ORDER BY SysStartTime) PrevStatus
    FROM myTable t
    FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM @start TO @end    -- FROM is strictly exclusive
) t

WHERE PrevStatus <> OrderStatus OR
    (rn = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM myTable t2
        FOR SYSTEM_TIME AT @start
        WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
            AND t2.OrderStatus <> t.OrderStatus
    ))
```

---

**Change Data Capture**

With CDC, it's somewhat more complex to set the query up, but I would imagine it would perform better.

You would typically use `fn_cdc_get_column_ordinal` to get the column number, then use that in the `WHERE` to filter against the update mask.

You also need to pass in the most recent received `@lsn` as `binary(10)` (or empty `binary(10)` if starting from fresh). You receive the new one back in the first resultset below.

```sql
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('myTable');  -- get the new low mark
DECLARE @to_lsn binary(10) = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn();  --get the new high mark
SELECT @to_lsn;    -- send back the new high, which becomes the low on the next run

SET @lsn = sys.fn_cdc_increment_lsn (@lsn);   -- get next LSN after the old high
IF (sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn (N'myTable') > @lsn)
    SELECT * FROM myTable;       -- need to do a full refresh
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ordinal int = sys.fn_cdc_get_column_ordinal (N'myTable', N'myCol');
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_myTable
        (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, 'all')
    WHERE sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set (__$update_mask, @ordinal) = 1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the query but not able to execute it. Will you help me to provide what need to be declare for start_lsn,end_lsn & ordinal ?

Comment: Have updated. But you really need to read up on how it works, it's pretty complex, and I haven't tested this code

Comment: They are using temporal tables, not change data capture

Answer (score 0):

Versionning cannot give you this information because in the case of "update for same value" a versionned row will be create but you will never be able to see if it is this column that have been modified or one other.

The only way to do that is to create a trigger in the table and count in some object.

In this cas I use one of the 10 user configurable counter of the profiler...
As an example, the code of the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER E_U_MY_TABLE
ON dbo.MY_TABLE
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT 1;
IF NOT UPDATE(OrderStatus)
   RETURN;
DECLARE @COUNT BIGINT = (SELECT cntr_value 
                         FROM   sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
                         WHERE instance_name = 'User counter 1') + 1;
EXEC sp_user_counter1 @COUNT;
GO
```

You can read it at any time with :

```
SELECT cntr_value 
FROM   sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE instance_name = 'User counter 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this using CTE's  In my case I'm looking for when a task moves from one queue to another queue and I need to capture the date that happened on a particular reporting date.

So in your case you could do something similar.

```
DECLARE @TaskType SMALLINT = 22
DECLARE @ActiveTasksIds TABLE (TaskId SMALLINT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @ActiveTasksIds
(
    TaskId
)
SELECT T.TaskId FROM TASK.Task AS T 
    INNER JOIN TASK.TaskStatus AS TS ON TS.TaskStatusId = T.TaskStatusId
WHERE T.TaskTypeId = @TaskType
    AND TS.IsFinal = 0

;WITH ActiveTaskHistory AS 
(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.TaskId ORDER BY T.ValidFrom ASC) AS RowNumber
, T.*
FROM TASK.Task FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL AS T
    INNER JOIN @ActiveTasksIds AS ATI ON T.TaskId = ATI.TaskId
WHERE T.TaskTypeId = @TaskType
)
, ATH_Before AS
(
SELECT * FROM ActiveTaskHistory ATH WHERE ATH.TaskQueueId IN (5, 10)
)
, ATH_AFTER AS 
(
SELECT * FROM ActiveTaskHistory ATH WHERE ATH.TaskQueueId = 28
)
SELECT ATH_Before.TaskId
    , ATH_Before.ValidFrom AS AHS_ValidFrom, ATH_EOHHS.ValidFrom AS EOHHS_ValidFrom
FROM ATH_Before
    INNER JOIN ATH_AFTER ON ATH_Before.TaskId = ATH_AFTER.TaskId
        AND ATH_Before.RowNumber + 1 = ATH_AFTER.RowNumber
WHERE 
    CAST(ATH_AFTER.ValidFrom AS DATE) = @ReportDate
```